# How to configure Docker with existing jenkins server?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm trying to understand the idea of how to use docker with Jenkins to setup CI/CD pipeline. I understood the flow but I'm confused with the process of using Docker with Jenkins.

Online every article talks about using Jenkins docker image to run Jenkins as a docker container but I dont want that.

I've a master and 2 slave VM's (Ubuntu) and I want to configure the CI/CD pipeline for docker which will pull the code from GitHub and build it and execute docker-file , push image to registry etc.

so should I install docker on my jenkins master and run the build on slaves using docker host uri ?

or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install docker on each slave host;  Config "docker host uri" for docker plugin:   unix:///var/run/docker.sock;  Make sure slave instance has RW access to local /var/run/docker.sock.

Or, install docker on master with "remote API" enabled;  Config "docker host uri":  http://<masterIP>:<remote API port>.